# aligning <li> from left to right within the same row

Tags: html, css

I want to create a 7 by 3 grid. Right now I do not know how to make the 3 blocks align next to each other. CSS is very confusing to me because I feel that there are too ways to do the same thing. I looked around for other examples and I think the `display: inline-block;` is supposed to do this for me but I can't seem to get it to work.

My html:

```
  <ul class="">

    <li class="">
      <ul class="inner">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    ... 6 more time

   </ul>
```

I want the `<li>` within the `<ul class="inner">` to align themselves from left to right but I dont know how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no valid CSS property of `border: inline-block;`, use `display: inline-block` on `.inner li`.

```css
ul.inner li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="">

  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: sorry i meant display

Comment: I've added a code snippet to my answer above, please check. Is that how you want it to be aligned in one line?

Comment: That is exactly how I want it but im still not getting the results I want on my page =/

Comment: @liondancer great to hear that! please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: @liondancer By the way,for the 7 x 3 grid, check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cmk5kfs/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with simpler markup and floating: http://jsfiddle.net/dLqaapmz/.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul > li:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following CSS:

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
.inner li{
float:left;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

//Body Contents

</body>
</html>
```

It is just Internal CSS (for your easiness), you can also use external CSS.
Hope this works :P